# Kendo MVVM Grid - Transport.create not being executed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have the following Kendo MVVM grid:

```
<div id="permissionTypeGrid" data-role="grid"
            data-sortable="true"
            data-scrollable="true"
            data-editable="true"
            data-toolbar="['create', 'save', 'cancel']"
            data-bind="source: permissionTypes"
            data-auto-bind="true"
            data-columns="[
                { 'field': 'PermissionType', 'width': 60  },
                { 'field': 'Description', 'width': 300 },
                { 'field': 'DisplayOrder', 'width': 60 },
                { 'command': [{name: 'destroy', text: 'Delete'}], 'width': 40 }
            ]">
        </div>
```

And the following view model:

```
 self.permissionTypeGrid = kendo.observable({
        isVisible: true,
        permissionTypes: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            schema: {
                parse: function (results) {
                    var permissionTypes = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.Data.Data.length; i++) {
                        var permissionType = {
                            PermissionType: results.Data.Data[i].SystemPermissionTypeCode,
                            Description: results.Data.Data[i].SystemPermissionTypeDescription,
                            DisplayOrder: results.Data.Data[i].DisplayOrder
                        };
                        permissionTypes.push(permissionType);
                    }
                    return permissionTypes;
                }
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/ServiceApi?method=Ref/SystemPermissionTypes",
                },
                create: {
                    url: "/api/ServiceApi?method=Ref/SystemPermissionTypes"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "/api/ServiceApi?method=Ref/SystemPermissionTypes"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "/api/ServiceApi?method=Ref/SystemPermissionTypes"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
    kendo.bind($("#permissionTypeGrid"), self.permissionTypeGrid);
```

Transport.read works fine, but the url for transport.create is never executed, nor is the parameterMap function. If I add a new record to the grid and then click "Save Changes", shouldn't the parameterMap function always be called? Also, an http request for the read is made as expected, but none gets generated for a create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You schema needs and ID.

If you add the line `model: { id: "DisplayOrder" },` after schema your create will begin firing when you click save changes.

Of course this is not likely to be the field that you will want to use for an ID but it should get you working.

```
schema: {
   model: { id: "DisplayOrder" },
   parse: function (results) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Something strange though. I added update to the transport, and yet when clicking save changes after modifying an existing row, it goes to transport.create instead of transport.update.

Comment: That is to say, in parameterMap the operation is create instead of update.